# How can I use setState in react-native after fetching new data?

Tags: react-native

In order to learn about react-native I'm trying to build a simple application.

This application initially prints "HELLO WORLD", afterwards it replaces this text with the contents of a json file that it fetches (in my test it contains {'Goodbye':'World'}).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class FetchTextTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      content: "HELLO WORLD",
    };
    fetch('http://echo.jsontest.com/goodbye/world').then(function(response) {
          response.json().then(function(data) {
            this.setState({content: JSON.stringfy(data)});
        });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.state.content}</Text>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FetchTextTest', () => FetchTextTest);
```

This works in that it displays HELLO WORLD and then fetches the json, but I don't manage to get it to display the new message. Instead I get this error:

```
Possible unhandles Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState
```

I feel like I'm doing it wrong. Am I not supposed to call setState from inside the constructor? Am I not getting the right context?

What is the expected way of doing this?

Comment: How you managed to fetch data from url?did you use npm fetch-js?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I fetch the file from my local machine. I omitted that part because I felt like 'http://localhost/test-file.json' wouldn't be helpful to anybody else, but the fetch operation works fine.

Comment: In case this is a problem, I've changed the url for one that will work outside my local machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do it like that

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          content: "",
        };
      }

      componentDidMount(){
         fetch('http://echo.jsontest.com/goodbye/world')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
           this.setState({content: responseJson});
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Text>{this.state.content.goodbye}</Text>
        )
      }
    }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FetchTextTest', () => FetchTextTest);
```

[expo link](https://snack.expo.io/r1NRUg8y-)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Could you please help me understand *why* it works? Is it because I can't call setState from within the constructor? Or maybe it's because arrow functions handle context in a different way than the ones I was using?